# SQL COUNT all rows with same or smaller value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to Access and SQL. I have two columns with dates. I'm trying to get for every date in the first column the amount of cells which have the same or an earlier date in the first column and a later date in the second column.

MyTable:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|    Incident Nr.     |    Incident Date    |  Completion Date |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      25.09.2007     |     31.10.2007   |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      26.09.2007     |     01.11.2007   |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      26.09.2007     |     04.12.2007   |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      30.11.2007     |                  |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

My Goal:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Date         |  Open Incidents  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      25.09.2007     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      26.09.2007     |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      30.11.2007     |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

- Incident Nr. 1: There are no earlier Incidents, only itself (25.09.2007). -> 1.
- Incident Nr. 2 & 3: Three Incidents (1x 25.09.2007, 2x 26.09.2007), none Completed (status as of 26.09.2007). -> 3.
- Incident Nr. 4    : Four Incidents, but 1 and 2 are already completed. -> 2.

My embarrassing attempt was:

```
SELECT [Incident Date], (SELECT COUNT([Incident Date]) FROM MyTable WHERE [Incident Date] <= [Incident Date]) AS [Open Incidents]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Incident Date];
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You would need to use table aliases for this. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-sql-from-clause-2a7d031c-6912-4e8c-a644-590940ddaed1

Comment: @StevenLemmens Thanks for the advice. That solves my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is actually pretty good.  But . . .

```
SELECT t.[Incident Date],
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable as t2
        WHERE t2.[Incident Date] <= t.[Incident Date] AND
              (t2.[Completion Date] >= t.[Incident Date] OR t2.[Completion Date] IS NULL)
       ) AS [Open Incidents]
FROM MyTable as t
GROUP BY t.[Incident Date];
```

Note the use of table aliases so it is clear whether the column references are to the inner query or the outer query.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly fine. Wasn't aware of the table aliases.

For the sake of completeness:
I replaced line 5:
(t2.[Completion Date] >= t.[Incident Date] OR t2.[Completion Date] IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, [aliases](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/access-sql-from-clause-2a7d031c-6912-4e8c-a644-590940ddaed1#bm2) are the key to solving this type of problem, as it requires referencing the source dataset more than once within the same query.

For what it's worth, this could also be solved using joins in the following way:

```
select t1.[incident date], count(*) as [open incidents]
from
    (select distinct [incident date] from MyTable) t1 inner join MyTable t2 on 
    (t1.[incident date] between t2.[incident date] and t2.[completion date])
group by
    t1.[incident date]
```

You may also want to account for incidents with no completion date, using:

```
select t1.[incident date], count(*) as [open incidents]
from
    (select distinct [incident date] from MyTable) t1 inner join MyTable t2 on 
    (
        (t1.[incident date] between t2.[incident date] and t2.[completion date]) or 
        (t1.[incident date] >= t2.[incident date] and t2.[completion date] is null)
    )
group by
    t1.[incident date]
```